# Using LIMIT and JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: Bands and Albums. Here is the structure

Bands:
id_band
name

Albums
id_album
id_band
name

So, I need a query that show all albums from the lasted inserted band.

And I try this:

```
SELECT bands.name, albums.name
FROM bands
JOIN albums ON albums.id_band = bands.id_band
ORDER BY bands.id_band DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But I get only the first album. Not all albums from the lasted inserted band. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT b.name,
       a.name
FROM bands b
JOIN albums a ON a.id_band = b.id_band
WHERE b.id_band = (SELECT max(id_band)
                   FROM bands)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT b.name, a.name
FROM (SELECT name, id_band
    FROM bands
    ORDER BY id_band DESC
    LIMIT 1) AS b
JOIN albums a ON a.id_band = b.id_band
```

Comment: Now I got  MySQL Error#: 1064

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem is that `NAME` is a reserved word. Try qualifying column references in the inline view, e.g. `FROM (SELECT d.name, d.id_band FROM bands d ORDER BY d.id_band DESC LIMIT 1) b`.

Comment: Error 1064 is a syntax error.  I tested the query as written above using MySQL 5.5, and it works fine with no error.  You may have mistyped the query.  Another possibility is that you're using MySQL 4.0 which doesn't support subqueries, but that's not likely since 4.0 is so old.